# Can you upload a zip file via the GCP command line to a Google Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am looking to deploy a zip file from command line to the GCP.

```sh
gcloud functions deploy NAME_HERE --runtime nodejs12 --trigger-http --source adapter.zip --entry-point gcpservice
```

The `--source` flag is pointing to a zip file. I am able to upload the zip file via the GUI, but not the command line. Am I doing something wrong or is this accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the Functions [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--source) you can use the flag `--source` for this scenarios

- A zip on a Cloud Storage Bucket (a zip file previously [uploaded to the cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects))
- Reference to source repository
- Local filesystem path (root directory of function source)

Having said that it is not possible to deploy a function using a local zip file.

The GCP console (web UI) first upload your zip file to a bucket and after takes this object and use it to deploy your function.